# Auto completion by typing TAB in TCL

Tags: scripting, shell, tcl

How can I achieve auto-completion of key words and directories by typing TAB (or something else) in TCL shell , tclsh.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/272710/rlwrap-tclsh-multi-word-autocompletion how to even get multi-word completion in tclsh.

Answer (score 4):

You need to find a copy of [tclreadline](http://tclreadline.sourceforge.net/), or switch to using [tkcon](http://tkcon.sourceforge.net/) (a graphical terminal written in Tcl that acts as a console) if using a GUI app is acceptable at all. FWIW, I can definitely recommend tkcon; the only reason I don't use it that much is because I'm often working with a custom build of Tcl that's hooked up to other things.

Comment: If at all possible, tkcon is the way to go. The tclrealine route is worth doing if you can't use a windowed environment, but it's certainly more of a hassle than tkcon (and tkcon is fantastic).