# How to write proc tcl script to use as command line on shell terminal, with added option, and you can also tab this option?

Tags: shell, tcl, tcsh

I want to write a tcl script, which will have a proc that when I execute the script, I can use the proc as a commandline when on tcsh Terminal, and I can also use option with it, and to also press Tab to display the options or to fill in if it's the only option.
For example, I want it to be able to function like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh
proc test {} {}
$ test file1 -option1 true -option2 file2 -Option3 0
```

- And like this: When I write:
  `$ test file1 -`
  And then press Tab, I can see:
  `-option1 -option2 -Option3`
  And if I continue to press O, the option automically fill in `-Option3`

Basically I'm trying to write a tcl script that let me use as a command line to use like other command, but with my option and function that I write in the script.

Comment: You want tab completion, correct? Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3050761/auto-completion-by-typing-tab-in-tcl

Comment: yeah thanks for the link, I'll look into it. But I want to know how to write a tcl script to use as a command line with option first.

Answer (score 1):

This really has nothing to do with `tcl`, and everything to do with `tcsh`'s `complete` builtin, which is what's used to define custom completions for specific commands. Example:

```sh
% complete ./foo.tcl "C/-o*/( -option1 -option2 -option3)/" "n/-option2/f/"
% ./foo -op<tab>
-option1 -option2 -option3 
% ./foo -option<cursor here>
% ./foo -option2 <tab>
<list of files>
```

See the man page for more details about the builtin.

If you bind the `complete-word-fwd` and `complete-line-back` editor commands to some key combinations you can use them to scroll through the possible choices.

So, basically, write a `tcsh` script that invokes `complete` to set up your desired completion choices, and `source` it. You can even create a `tcl` script that creates the script for your arguments; exact details would depend on what you're using to parse them - `tcllib`'s `cmdline` package, your custom code, or something else?

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's exactly what I'm looking for. Could you also go into detail how do I link the command to a script (or do I need to copy the script - the foo.tcl file, into my current dir everytime, I also don't want to use the full path of /dir/foo.tcl, as it is too long). Also for the option, How do I write in tcl to customize my code? I want it to be more flexible, to understand:
`foo file1 -option1 a -option2 b` , `foo file1 -option2 b -option1 a` .
I only know how to use argv, but it will takes all inputs after foo as variables, and is limited by the positions.

Comment: Wait nevermind, I figure I can use alias
`alias foo /dir/foo.tcl`, to link the script to cmd I want to customize, haha, I'm so stupid, I will try to figure out how to customize the option too

Comment: Hum...So I try to write:
`proc foo {args} {
while{[llength $args]} {
switch [lindex $args 0] {
"-opt1" {set opt1 [lindex $args 1]; set args [lrange $args 2 end]}
"-opt2" {set opt2 [lindex $args 1]; set args [lrange $args 2 end]}
default break
}
}
puts "option is $opt1 $opt2" }
foo $argv `

Then on Terminal, I use:
`% foo -opt1 a -opt2 b`
But I get error: `can't read opt1: no such variable`, Do you happen to know why?

Comment: Ok nevermind, proc treat a variable list as 1 variable only, proc can understand a list of variables as a list with args, but variable that's a list (like a = list [1 2 3 4], will be treated as 1 "1 2 3 4" variable

Comment: `foo {*}$argv` is one way around that.

Comment: thks a lot, that's exactly what I'm looking for. I also figure out that using any other arguement instead of args also resolve this issue too